# Multi-Level sorting/ grouping with CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid, collectionviewsource

I couldn't figure out how to do the CollectionViewSource filtering in XAML, so I create my CollectionViewSource in code and pass the View as a property via MVVM...  I'm not sure if that is part of the issue, but here's my problem:

In a WPF DataGrid, I want to sort a list of documents by date and then by name.  I tried just adding multiple SortDesccriptions, but that doesn't seem to work.  I tried adding in grouping...  And I'm not sure how the SortDescriptions interact with the LiveSortingProperties, and why the Live ones don't allow for a sort direction.  I've tried multiple iterations of different configurations.  This is what I have, now:

```
_docsCVS = new CollectionViewSource();

_docsCVS.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("DocDate"));
_docsCVS.LiveGroupingProperties.Add("DocDate");
_docsCVS.IsLiveGroupingRequested = true;

_docsCVS.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription() { PropertyName = "DocDate", Direction = ListSortDirection.Descending });
_docsCVS.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription() { PropertyName = "DocName", Direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending });
_docsCVS.LiveSortingProperties.Add("DocDate");
_docsCVS.LiveSortingProperties.Add("DocName");
_docsCVS.IsLiveSortingRequested = true;

_docsCVS.LiveFilteringProperties.Add("SourceId");
_docsCVS.IsLiveFilteringRequested = true;
_docsCVS.Filter += _docs_CVSFilter;

_docsCVS.Source = Docs;
```

The filtering works as expected.  But I can't figure out how to get the docs to sort (or group) first by Date (descending) and then by Name (ascending).  And then to maintain proper sorting/grouping if docs are added or removed.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

J

Comment: what is `Docs`?

Comment: So you want to sort the groups by `DocDate` and not the items within a group, right? Not that it's an actual difference to the solution, but lets be clear with the expected outcome

Comment: I want to sort by date(desc) and then by name(asc)...  Or group by date (dec) and sort by name within date group.

Comment: Docs is an ObservableCollection

Comment: @DigitalCamel why `new CollectionViewSource()`;

Comment: @LeiYang I was going for brevity in my post...  It's wrapped in a conditional, first checking for null.  If not null, then it just returns the existing instance.